# Should all accented characters use html entities?

Tags: html, character-encoding, html-entities, diacritics

I am working with a large number of HTML files that are mostly encoded as utf-8. There are accented characters galore as many are in French. I have been converting them to HTML entities as I go, but I noticed that even in IE5.5 (according IE tester) the nonconverted accented characters are displaying properly.

Should I be concerned with character display and convert them all to HTML entities just to be on the safe side?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the files are UTF-8 encoded, you should set the `Content-Type` header to be `text/html; charset=UTF-8` and have an equivalent meta tag on the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

This gives the browser all the information for displaying UTF-8 characters correctly. There is no need to encode accented characters.

Comment: I always thought this meta tag by itself was fairly useless. In order for the browser to read the tag it either has to know or guess at the charset by another means and at least get "close enough".

Answer (score 5):

There is normally no reason to use entities for characters like accented letters. Using them is valid but tends to obfuscate the source code and may therefore cause errors.

However, in some cases the entities are needed. The reasons are not related to browsers but to the authoring side. In particular, if you need to *edit* the files using an editor or an authoring program that does not handle accented letters well, you may find entities useful. The same applies if the data has to pass through some software that has similar problems. And in some cases, you need to work within an environment where you have no control over HTTP headers and the headers specify an encoding that does not let you enter all characters directly.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you need to remember is French is part of the UTF-8 family along with Portuguese, Spanish, etc, so they will display properly with a UTF-8 tag in place and providing the browser is also using UTF-8 for the page.

The problem is when a person using a browser that is forcing another charset comes to the page, this will break the un-encoded characters. This happens a bit here in Brazil where many browsers are not set for automatic detection of the charset and are set to ISO-8859-1 that is common here.

So where possible encode all of your "special" characters for the most universal access possible.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Do you know what situations lead to a browser forcing another character set?

Comment: There are 2 factors, the first and most common is some browsers in some languages don't use UTF-8 as the default as they aren't UTF-8 languages or UTF-8 isn't as common as another charset in those countries, the second is user preference, e.g. a site needed the charset changed and the user forgot to change it back.