# Proper way to type French accents in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a general question about displaying French characters in HTML documents... I see other questions about people encountering problems or specific cases, but my question is just about the general approach:

Will putting `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` of my document ensure that French accents, typed regularly (without using HTML entities), show up in all the main browsers?

Comment: As long as the document is truly in UTF-8. it should work

Comment: You should store your HTML documents in UTF-8 as well.

Comment: No, HTTP headers override your `<meta>` tags.

Comment: Not sure I follow... how do you know if it is saved in UTF (using something like Adobe Dreamweaver)? Do I have to worry about the HTTP headers? Can someone provide a more complete answer or suggest a resource to help me find the answer?

Comment: I found some more thorough responses here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587056/should-all-accented-characters-use-html-entities

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ampersand code. For example: `&ntilde;` for a ñ ( n with tilde ). That is a spanish example, but you can look here for french ones:
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html#foreign

Comment: I'm aware of HTML entities / special character codes. My question is if the line <meta charset="UTF-8"> will allow me to not use them. I want to be able to type special characters (like French accents: é, è, ...) directly without using special codes.

Comment: They will allow you to use them, as long as your `charset` supports them (UTF-8 does)